# How to change a prop.table command to get the proportions for genders separately in r

Tags: r

With the command `prop.table(xtabs(Freq ~ Gender + Admit, data=df))` I get this:

```
    Admit
Gender     Admitted   Rejected
  Male   0.54876742 0.33547696
  Female 0.09539121 0.02036442
```

How do I have to change my command that it calculates the table for male and female separately? So that the male row adds up to 100% alone and same with female.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out the solution is

```
prop.table(xtabs(Freq ~ Gender + Admit, data=df), margin = 1)
```

If I were interested in columns proportions instead of rows, I'd have to write 2 instead of 1 after margin.